What is the latest version of Windows server 64 bit that supports Paradox database engine (BDE)?
I need to upgrade to a newer Windows Server OS than 2008 R2 64 bit. Paradox database Engine (BDE) on later OSs gives the following errors.
When running on Windows 2012 R2 Server or later, I get this error:

DBD32.EXE - Application Error


The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application.


And the Event log error is the following:
The application (Borland Delphi 7.0, from vendor Borland) has the following problem: Borland Delphi 7.0 is incompatible with this version of Windows. For more information, contact Borland.
Does anyone know of how to use this database on this or a later OS?

What version of BDE are you trying to use? We still unfortunately run Paradox-based software on Windows 10 (equivalent to Server 2019) using BDE 5.1 without having to do anything special.
